# Como puedo pasar u obtener el usuario logeado para un sistema de publicaciones en angular y django?

Tags: python, django

Estamos desarrollando nuestro proyecto en angular y no podemos encontrar la forma de hacer que las publicaciones se asocien a un usuario (el logeado en ese momento) para luego poder hacer un apartado de "Mis publicaciones". Estamos trabajando con Angular y Django. Les voy a proporcionar los archivos principales que creo que habria que modificar (models.py, views.py, el archivo ts del authService que estamos utilizando)
Cabe destacar que claramente tenemos un formulario que se envia, pero no he logrado que entre en esta pregunta. No se si con esos bloques de codigo alcance para solucionar mi pregunta, en cualquier caso, puedo proveer el codigo de los demas archivos. Desde ya muchas gracias, espero sus respuestas.

models.py:

```
class Publicacion(models.Model):
nombrePerro = models.CharField(max_length=30)
fotoPerro = models.ImageField(upload_to="./perros", null=True, blank=True)
edadPerro = models.CharField(max_length=20)
SEXO_CHOICES = [
    ('Macho', 'Macho'),
    ('Hembra', 'Hembra'),
]
sexoPerro = models.CharField(max_length=15, choices=SEXO_CHOICES)

TAMANO_CHOICES = [
    ('Pequeño', 'Pequeño'),
    ('Mediano', 'Mediano'),
    ('Grande', 'Grande'),
]
tamanioPerro = models.CharField(max_length=10, choices=TAMANO_CHOICES)

#Funcion para retornar algo cuando llamo al objeto
def __str__(self):
    return self.nombrePerro

from django.contrib.auth.models import AbstractBaseUser, BaseUserManager, PermissionsMixin
from django.db import models

class UserManager(BaseUserManager):
def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    if not email:
        raise ValueError('El Email es obligatorio')
    email = self.normalize_email(email)
    user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
    user.set_password(password)
    user.save(using=self._db)
    return user

def create_superuser(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', True)
    extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', True)
    return self.create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)

class User(AbstractBaseUser, PermissionsMixin):
email = models.EmailField(unique=True)
name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
password = models.CharField(max_length=128)
is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
is_staff = models.BooleanField(default=False)

# Agregar related_name personalizado para evitar conflictos
groups = models.ManyToManyField(
    Group,
    verbose_name='groups',
    blank=True,
    related_name='custom_user_set',
)
user_permissions = models.ManyToManyField(
    Permission,
    verbose_name='user permissions',
    blank=True,
    related_name='custom_user_set',
)

USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
REQUIRED_FIELDS = []

objects = UserManager()

def registrar_usuario(request):
if request.method == 'POST':
    email = request.data.get('email')
    name = request.data.get('name')
    apellido = request.data.get('apellido')
    telefono = request.data.get('telefono')
    provincia = request.data.get('provincia')
    localidad = request.data.get('localidad')

    try:
        user = User.objects.create_user(email=email, password='password', name=name,                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         apellidoUsuario=apellido, telefono=telefono, provincia=provincia, localidad=localidad)
        return JsonResponse({'mensaje': 'Usuario registrado exitosamente'})
    except IntegrityError:
        return JsonResponse({'mensaje': 'Correo duplicado'}, status=400)
```

views.py:

```
class PublicacionList(generics.ListAPIView):
queryset = Publicacion.objects.all()
serializer_class = PublicacionSerializer

class PublicacionCreateView(APIView):
@permission_classes([IsAuthenticated])
def post(self, request):
    serializer = PublicacionSerializer(data=request.data)
    if serializer.is_valid():
        nueva_publicacion = serializer.save()
        
        # Asocia la publicación al usuario autenticado
        nueva_publicacion.usuario = request.user
        nueva_publicacion.save()
        
        return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
    return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

class RegisterView(APIView):
def post(self, request):
     serializer = UserSerializer(data=request.data)
     serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
     serializer.save()
     return Response(serializer.data)


class LoginView(APIView):
def post(self, request):
    email = request.data.get('email')  
    password = request.data.get('password')

    user = User.objects.filter(email=email).first()

    if user is None:
        raise AuthenticationFailed('User not found')
    
    if not user.check_password(password):
        raise AuthenticationFailed('Contraseña incorrecta')
    
    payload ={
        'id': user.id,
        'exp': datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(minutes=60),
        'iat': datetime.datetime.utcnow()
    }

    token = jwt.encode(payload, 'secret', algorithm='HS256')
    
    response = Response()
    response.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True)
    response.data = {
        'jwt': token
    }
    return response

class UserView(APIView):

def get(self, request):
    token = request.COOKIES.get('jwt')

    if not token:
        raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated')
    
    try:
        payload = jwt.decode(token, 'secret', algorithms=['HS256'])
    except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
        raise AuthenticationFailed('Unauthenticated')
    
    user = User.objects.filter(id=payload['id']).first()
    serializer= UserSerializer(user)

    return Response(serializer.data)


class LogoutView(APIView):
def post(self, request):
    response = Response()
    response.delete_cookie('jwt')
    response.data = {
        'message': 'success'
    }
    return response
```

authService.ts:

```
@Injectable({
providedIn: 'root'
})
export class AuthService {
constructor(public jwtHelper: JwtHelperService) { }
public isAuthenticated(): boolean {
const token = localStorage.getItem('token');
if (token && !this.jwtHelper.isTokenExpired(token)) {
  return true;
} else {
  return false;
}
 }
 }
```